# Unable to get the MSI credentials with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, identity

I am working with the NodeJs Azure Function V2 and I want to get the secret from Key-Vault.
I tried with following reference. [Here's a link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-node/).

I am using [***ms-rest-azure***](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms-rest-azure) NPM library package.

My code as follows:

```
    function getKeyVaultCredentials(){
        return msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({resource: "https://my-keyvault-DNS-url.vault.azure.net",msiEndpoint: process.env["MSI_ENDPOINT"],msiSecret:process.env["MSI_SECRET"]});
    }

    function getKeyVaultSecret(credentials) {
      var keyVaultClient = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
      return keyVaultClient.getSecret("https://my-keyvault-DNS-url.vault.azure.net", 'secret', "mySecretName");
    }

    getKeyVaultCredentials().then(
        getKeyVaultSecret
    ).then(function (secret){
        console.log(`Your secret value is: ${secret.value}.`);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        throw (err);
    });
```

The function call executed successfully but never getting the credential.

***Note*** : 
    I have enabled the MSI identity and given access to kevault for that Azure function.

The error I am getting is as follows:
    
    `MSI: Failed to retrieve a token from "http://127.0.0.1:410056/MSI/token/?resource=https://my-keyvault-DNS-url.vault.azure.net&api-version=2017-09-01" with an error: {"ExceptionMessage":"AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://my-keyvault-DNS-url.vault.azure.net was not found in the tenant named 6620834b-d11e-44cb-9931-2e08b6ee81cc00. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: 1f25ac6c-01e0-40d8-8146-269f22d49f001\r\nCorrelation ID: 4beede0c-2e83-4bcc-944d-ba4e8ec2c6834\r\nTimestamp: 2019-03-29 02:54:40Z","ErrorCode":"invalid_resource","ServiceErrorCodes":["500011"],"StatusCode":400,"Message":null,"CorrelationId":"e6e8108d-e605-456b-8fb6-473962dcd5d678"}`

I might doing some silly/blunder - please help!!

Comment: share more "about never getting credential"?  eg. did the call ever made?  If made, was it succeeded or failed?  If failed, what the error etc.

Comment: @Suwat - I deployed the application to cloud and made a postman call.
I am getting success message as follows:
Executed 'Functions.NodeJsFunctionAppV2' (Succeeded, Id=8840ef3f-82e8-4e0c-a08e-a1c5a2a3b9fd)

Comment: @Suwat - updated my question with exception i have encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some subtle fixes that your code needs

1. `resource` should be set to `https://vault.azure.net`. This basically has to be the resource in general, not your instance as such.
2. The method is actually `getSecret('<KEYVAULT_URI>', '<SECRET_NAME>', '<SECRET_VERSION>')`

Here is how your code should look like at the end

```
function getKeyVaultCredentials() {
  return msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({
    resource: 'https://vault.azure.net'
  });
}

function getKeyVaultSecret(credentials) {
  var keyVaultClient = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
  return keyVaultClient.getSecret(
    'https://my-keyvault-DNS-url.vault.azure.net',
    'mySecretName',
    ''
  );
}

getKeyVaultCredentials()
  .then(getKeyVaultSecret)
  .then(function(secret) {
    console.log(`Your secret value is: ${secret.value}.`);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    throw err;
  });
```